# What kind of relation is this?

Tags: sql, database, doctrine, uml, symfony

I have an abstract class called "classCountry". This class will be extended by differents subclass like "classUk", "classFrance", "classItaly" etc

Is it oneToOne ? manyToMany ?

I'm using doctrine in a symfony app but I think it is not relevant here.

Edit: I think it is a relation oneToOne. If it is not please feel free to tell me. It would help me.

Edit2: After some searches It should be a oneTOMany relation

Edit3: After additional searches I have found you can't use OneToMany relation in a super mapped class of doctrine see here http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html

I think i'm going to use oneToOne relation. If this isn't the good answer I will come back here to mention it.

Comment: I've heard that question too many times... :(

Comment: Sorry.  I'm creating doctrine annotation in the MappedSuperclass of my project and I need to be sure about I'm doing.

Comment: @jarlh please sir can you confirm it is a oneToOne relation ?

Comment: My comment was just a joke... (Consider human relations...)

Comment: @jarlh ok cool :-) after search I think it is a "oneToMany" relation

Comment: The `<<extends>>` relation is almost only used with use cases, not with classes. Do you mean generalization/specialization?

Comment: @Thomas Kilian. I'm sorry I can answer I do not have the knowledge for it. I'm creating a what is called a "MappedSuperclass" with doctrine. I just need to know what kind of relation is this. To create an annotation into my abstract class. Nothing else.

Comment: It rather looks like you are after the database model, not the UML model.

Comment: Are you new to object oriented programming? I don't understand how you could have a "classUk"? Instead the UK could be the name part of the "classCountry". Also, I wouldn't call it "classCountry", but instead "Country". You might have a sub class of "Continent". Do you now see my point? I hope this helps.

Comment: @Alvin Bunk. Yes sorry if my example was not a good one. I would have an abstract class called Countries and then sub class called Uk, France, etc. But anyway the solution of my problem was solved by doctrine documentation.

Comment: But you are missing the point. "UK" would be an "instance" of a County, not a sub class... But I will leave it up to you.

Comment: Yes you are and was right. My example should have been: I have a mother class called Continents And then subclass called Uk, France etc. Bye

Comment: Just to give a good example of classes I would suggest abstract class Country and subclasses Kingdom, Republic, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're describing a generalization. In generalization you do not specify the multiplicity as it doesn't make sense. Thus you can call it neither oneToOne not oneToMany not any other kind.

At the meta level (i.e. description of relationship between classes, not entities) generalization is a manyToMany relationship in UML, however specific languages have either manyToMany (e.g. C++) or oneToMany (e.g. Java).

Comment: Yes you are right. Your answer is the best explainsation. It did not make sense to specifiy multiplicity. I'm new with doctrine and symfony and I was bilieving I had to specify a relation. I was wrong.